# File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/foundation-global

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass, zurb-foundation

I cannot get this to work with any import file in sass file, even with activeadmin(`File to import not found or unreadable: active_admin/mixins`)

The weird thing is that is no such directory called foundation in my app assets directory, neither active_admin when I install the gem and generate their files as documented.

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/foundation-global.
              Load paths:
                /Users/me/app/assets/stylesheets
                /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
                /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
                Compass::SpriteImporter
```

One more thing is, as it could help to address the issue, that I am using RVM. And it is so weird that I actually have the gem path in `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head` when I echo $GEM_PATH but the error is showing different gem path above.

Here is my Gemfile in my app:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'compass'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'zurb-foundation', '~> 4.0.4'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

gem 'activeadmin'
```

Is there anyone can tell me what is going on here? I have been living with it for weeks. Since I couldn't fix it, I have to remove the `foundation_and_overrides.css` and `active_admin.css` every time I restart the server or every time I make changes to the sass files.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add to your Compass config.rb:

```
    require "zurb-foundation"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I'm using Codekit to compile my scripts, so this was all it was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Run `bundle install` from within your project's directory (the one that has the `Gemfile`).

### UPD 2013-04-01

Bundler creates a separate set of gems. It seems that your project is unaware of it.

Try doing `bundle uninstall`, moving the `Gemfile` away from the project and installing the gems globally. If your project starts working, then you'll know where the problem is.

A separate set of gems can also be maintained by RVM's [GemSets](https://rvm.io/gemsets/). Please check that too.

### UPD 2013-04-01 #2

Please run `which ruby` and `which compass` both as yourself and as the user running your application. Here's an example how to do that on Linux, on Mac in should be similar:

```
sudo su -ls /bin/bash www-data
which ruby
which compass
```

Please write a comment to this question with results for your user and web application user.

### UPD 2013-04-02

Try using the `compass-rails` gem rather than `compass`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I run bunble install every time I want to install gem. These gems foundation, activeadmin or any gem which uses sass was installed but somehow the import inside of any of these gems throwing error.

Comment: Hey Inguyen55, i do see that you're an experienced developer. Please don't consider my very basic suggestion to be an insult. We'll investigate your issue together, debug it step by step. There's no need to downvote the first step. :( I've updated my answer to address your reply, please check that and reply again.

Comment: Hi lolmaus, thank you for you help. I removed the negative vote, but error still throwing. It looks like the sass-rails is not working with import path though while other sass features still functioning.

Comment: I'm on Mac. When I run with sudo and with user both results are identical: `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/ruby` `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/compass`

Comment: Did you run it as a different user with sudo? This Ruby 1.8 must come from somewhere.

Comment: The 1.8 Ruby seems to be preinstalled on your OS. Maybe it's defined in your web server configuration?

Comment: That could be a good direction but I have no idea with WEBrick.

Comment: Thanks lomaus! I also tried that. No luck! It's annoyed that I can use pure css files by using `require` in css file instead of @import in sass. But, you know? we love sass!

Comment: Could you please share your project structure and content of configuration files?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and found the solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18803119/661471

Quoting from that answer:

> This is a result of running rails g foundation:install with a
>   different version of foundation than the one you have installed.
>   foundation-global is no longer imported as part of
>   foundation_and_overrides.scss.